# Limiting URL entry with a PHP variable

Tags: php, url, variables

I am trying to limit what a user can see to only his/her own details. I am passing a PHP variable through the URL bar so it displays solely their own information, but if they edit the ID number, they can view others' details?

The code I currently have is shown here:

```
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]);

include "../adminscripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' AND role='Student' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount == 0) {
header("location: http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php");
exit();
}
?>

<?php
// Get a list of all items and display them in alphabetically
include "../adminscripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

//Check to see the URL variable exists in the database
$dynamicList = "";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
include "../adminscripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);

***********************************************************************************
***********************************************************************************

// If the ID does not exist the display this message.
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM StudentAttendance WHERE StudentID='$id' ORDER BY AttendanceDate DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $AttendanceDate = $row["AttendanceDate"];
        $AttendanceStatus = $row["AttendanceStatus"];
        $Notes = $row["Notes"];
        $dynamicList .= '<tr style="font-size:15px;">
  <td>' . $AttendanceDate . '</td>
  <td>' . $AttendanceStatus . '</td>
  <td>' . $Notes . '</td>
</tr>';
    }
} else {
    $AttendanceDate = "nil";
    $AttendanceStatus = "nil";
    $Notes = "nil";
}
} else {
echo "Something is missing which means we can't display this page! Sorry for the inconvenience and please try again later!";
exit();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

I have tried putting the following if statement in where I have placed the asterisks in the above code...

```
if ($id != $managerID) {
    $id = $managerID;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working... Am I putting it in the right place? As far as I can tell I've used the correct variables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ummm all of those stars might cause you some issues...

Comment: I've just put them in for the purpose of this question @Neal - they're not actually there in the code :)

Comment: Can you just encrypt/decrypt the ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you already have a logged user and the ID, so why don't you just use `$_SESSION["id"]` instead of `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jeroen - I have tried using `$_SESSION["id"]` instead of `$_GET['id']` but, although it is displaying the correct data, the user can still change the value in the URL and it will navigate to another student's data...

Comment: I think maybe I might be confused as to where you mean to change it!

Comment: @Zulu Irminger Everywhere, if `$_SESSION["id"]` contains the id of the currently logged in student and he / she can only change his / her own data, there is no need for `$_GET['id']` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I'd been at it for too long and had tunnel vision! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change your thinking a little.  When they login, set a session variable that is their user ID, and use that instead of the querystring.  Or continue to use the querystring, but validate it against the session user ID and make sure it is their info they are trying to visit.